# iOS: Can i create my own store with consumable in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

i want to build the app and it has consumable in-app purchase feature.
Users can buy coins (consumable in-app purchase), and spend their coins to buy some virtual goods.

The question is, can i build my own store for them to spend their coins?
Every item has each price, users tap on it to buy and pay with coin. All those items on this store can be remote updated online by me, i can change the price, data, add new item every time i want.

So will it fit with Apple policies? Or each item on my store have to be approved by Apple?

And if it works, when user switch the device (change their phone) , how can i do the restore purchase feature?

Answer (score 0):

AS long as your user buy coins, what he does with it is not the matter of Apple. A good example is Free-2-Play games like "Clash of Clans". You only have to create an inApp for each pack of coins you want to sell.

In short, you have to store the coins credit of each user on server side and restore it when your user is authenticated.

If you need a simple solution without any server of yours, I recently used Parse (parse.com) that let you have a database without having your own server.

Comment: So, the main question is i can build my own store and update items on it without Apple approval? I already have a server, all i have to do is building an API for my app can use it, everytimes user access to my store, it will load all items from my server, right?

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with that, as far as I know since the general purpose of your app is fair. I guess if you try to make your app something like a black market, Apple will blame you. The f2p games I mentioned before (and a lot of its kind) does a lot of little adjustments on their shop in game to maximize the profits so I don't know why you wouldn't be allowed to do the same things.